# Dialog added in installshield wizard doesn't show up : error 1314 specified path 0 is unavailable

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield

I created a new installshield project from scratch. I added a new dialog to be shown in the installation wizard at `User Interface -> Dialogs` path. My dialog simply has a text box in which I have to take a web service URL from the user.

Then at `Behavior and Logic -> Custom Actions and Sequences` path I added the dialog under `Sequnces -> Installation -> User Interface`. My Dialog is placed right after `SetupCompletedError`, `SetupInterrupted` and `SetupCompleteSuccess` dialogs.

When I run the installer to test it I get following error message box:

> error 1314 the specified path 0 is unavailable

[image]

If I remove my dialog I am able to see the welcome screen and few default wizard steps. The moment I add my dialog I get the above error. Can someone tell me if I'm missing something really basic step here?

Comment: What is the value of your INSTALLDIR property? Looks like that parameter, or one of the other has a default porperty value of "0". you can find property manager at "under Behavior and Logic, click Property Manager"

Comment: Yes. you nailed it. That was the thing :) Thanks. It helped. You might want to add this as an answer.

Comment: I don't know if this was ever fixed but my memory of InstallShield was that you had to be on the lookout for properties with a value of 0  all the time.   The tool would frequently assign this as the default value of a property whenever you used it in various places when really all you wanted to do was reference a property not define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, you probably want to create a dialog using the interior dialog template and then wire it into the wizard loop by changing the control events on the back and next buttons of the previous, the new and the next dialog.   Only InstallWelcome should have an entry in the Install UI Sequence table.   The way you are doing it now  wouldn't visually fit into the flow of the rest of your installer.  It would be displayed before InstallWelcome  and you wouldn't have any way of going "back" to update the input.

Also be sure to test your uninstall / maintenance (change and repair) scenarios to make sure it looks and behaves correctly there also.

Comment: That was exactly the case :) Actually I had used `Blank Dialog` template as I was not aware of this `Interior Wizard Panel` dialog and then it all got messed up. Once I used `Interior Wizard Panel` and configured it on click of next button of welcome screen then everything fell in place.